# ASP.NET Multiple Themes in One Site

Tags: asp.net, themes

I have an App_Themes directory, and also Master pages for a ASP.NET website.

Can I use 2 different themes based on the master page?

Comment: Can you explain "based on the master page?". You cannot set a theme in the masterpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN has an article about [ASP.NET Master Pages And Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx#MasterPagesAndThemes)

> You cannot directly apply an ASP.NET
>   theme to a master page. If you add a
>   theme attribute to the @ Master
>   directive, the page will raise an
>   error when it runs.
>
> However, themes are applied to master
>   pages under these circumstances:
>
> - If a theme is defined in the content
>     page. Master pages are resolved in the
>     context of content pages, so the
>     content page's theme is applied to the
>     master page as well.
> - If the site as a whole is configured
>     to use a theme by including a theme
>     definition in the pages Element
>     (ASP.NET Settings Schema) element.

In addition to the above you can see the section about [Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx). You can [change theme programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx)

**Example from MSDN**

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Request.QueryString["theme"])
    {
        case "Blue":
            Page.Theme = "BlueTheme";
            break;
        case "Pink":
            Page.Theme = "PinkTheme";
            break;
    }
}
```

But you cannot use two themes at the same time, that does not make any sense. You could however change the theme based on which masterpage is used.

To answer your question in your comment, yes you can have different themes for different sub-folders. This is from MSDN:

> A theme setting in the Web.config file
>   applies to all ASP.NET Web pages in
>   that application. Theme settings in
>   the Web.config file follow normal
>   configuration hierarchy conventions.
>   For example, to apply a theme to only
>   a subset of pages, you can put the
>   pages in a folder with their own
>   Web.config file or create a 
>   element in the root Web.config file to
>   specify a folder. For details, see
>   Configuring Specific Files and
>   Subdirectories.

Comment: Do you know if you can use a `<pages styleSheetTheme="...">` in web.config in a sub directory?  If so, you might be able to separate it that way.