# Two Sites from one project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

We're publishing two websites based out of one project.

The main site is a asp.net web forms web application, written in c#. The next one we are creating will derive from this. We want to be able to maintain both sites by editing the same code.
So we don't have to edit simple changes in both projects.

The difference between the sites, are the css file(and maybe the master page).
And some dependant code, like f.ex. login.

I figured I could do this using different build configurations.

**First of all:**
*Is this a good way to solve it?*

**If yes:**

1. How do I create a web.config file to load a different settings?
2. How do I load different css file(and different master page).
3. How do I create dependent code?

**If no:**

*What would be?*

Thanks for any help and tips contributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  `css files` you can change it on `application_start` event (assuming that you have two different host for the application).

 You can change the master page at `preInit` event of page.

The better approach can be

1. Create you [business logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx) in a separate project.
2. Try to create different [Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951092/asp-net-multiple-themes-in-one-site) for different Client.
3. Set the [theme on](http://forums.asp.net/t/1558473.aspx/1) `Application_Start` event.

You can also take advantage of [DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865695/applying-dependency-injection-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-application-built-using-mv) (dependency injection) to call different method of different classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've been reading up on your links, and will try this out in my project.(I would vote your answer up, but can't yet)

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off creating two projects, but creating shared code as a dll that both projects can share.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on custom web CMS and therefore i have to create two websites doing some common functionalty. Here are my steps

- Create a solution.
- Add a class library type project
- Add two different websites
- Give reference of class library to both websites and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only problem with my project is that we have around 50 pages, heavy with code. Which are almost identical on both web sites, and that are still under development. Still I will take this into consideration :).

Comment: Are you using role based security in your application ?

Comment: Yes, and the two different sites does have different logic applied here.

Comment: then make 2 roles as your for your websites and load different masterpages for your users. 1 website 2 different masterpages and login mechanism. check these links [link1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1464861.aspx/1) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632166/load-different-master-pages-for-different-users) and